# use siunitx to report percentages in parentheses behind values

Tags: tables, siunitx

First time I am using `siunitx` to format a table of mine which works fine. Now I would like to add after each value the percentage of some (unreported) total. The values are 5-figure integers and the percentages should be rounded to one decimal.

My attempt so far has been to hijack the uncertainty-option, round to one decimal but use `zero-decimal-to-integer` to format the integers nicely, and add a percentage sign to the error. Using some trial-and-erro and other SE-pages, I arrived at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-alignment=right, 
                  round-mode=places, 
                  round-precision=1, 
                  table-format=5.3,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer,
                  input-symbols={()}]}
{title}         \\
11111(1.11)     \\
55555(55.55)     \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which works but lacks two more elements.

1. The percentage sign: If I use `(1.11{\percent})` I am surprised to get `undefined control sequence`.
2. An empty space before the open parenthesis: I though `table-space-text-pre={(}` would achieve this but it won't.

As I said, this is my first attempt at `siunitx`, so I am hoping I just misunderstand things. Also, I suspect that there is a more elegant way of achieving the same output but couldn't find it in the wealth of package options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to add pair of braces around the contents of the parenthesis, in order to make it non-part of the aligned numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\mypc}[1]{\hfill(\SI{#1}{\percent})}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-alignment=right,
                  round-mode=places,
                  round-precision=1,
                  table-format=5.0,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer,
                  input-symbols={()\%},,
                  table-space-text-post={\enspace(11.1\,\%)},
                  table-align-text-post=true]}
{title} \\
11111 \mypc{1.11} \\
55555 \mypc{5.55} \\
55555 \mypc{55.55}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! However, when the percentage is double-digit (say, 55.55%), the parentheses are no longer-right aligned (even if I use `\SI{2.1}`), as is the title. Also, is there a way to control the space between value and parentheses as this seems a bit large?

Comment: Did you try using `num` for the  percentages?

Comment: Yes, as you suggested.

Comment: I'll take a look into the spacing. Could you post a small representative example code?

Comment: The code above (and your screenshot) already sow the spacing issue. It is quite large, about four digits but spacing of one digit would be enough. I noticed that leaving `\,` out yields the same spacing. I did add the 55.55 to the OP.

Comment: The large spacing is mainly due to a small inconsistency:  the table-fomat,  sets the space for 3 decimal digits, but the real numbers are integers, and anyway, round-precision is set to 1. So which values do you really need?

Comment: I see, setting it to 5.1 helps and setting it to 5.0 eliminates space between value and parentheses. It appears as if the `\,` has no effect. `round-precision=1` is needed to round percentages to one decimal (see OP). Any idea what to do about the odd alignment when percentages are double-digit?

Comment: It is possible to make them left-aligned with a sensible spacing with a macro. I'll edit  my answer in a moment. However, having the numbers centred would result in a nicer  look for the column heads

Comment: I would need numbers and title right-aligned, as before (because other columns are also right-aligned). I am curious to see, the commands are still foreign to me.

Comment: Please see if the new code provides what you want.